# React Router serverside rendering errors: Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `history` was not specified in `RoutingContext`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, hapi.js

I'm setting up a simple toy app to learn React/Hapi and everything is working well till I try and set up serverside routing. The server runs without error and renders "/" properly with hello world.

However when I navigate to "/test" I get the following errors.

```
Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `history` was not specified in `RoutingContext`.
Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `location` was not specified in `RoutingContext`.
Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `routes` was not specified in `RoutingContext`.
Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `params` was not specified in `RoutingContext`.
Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `components` was not specified in `RoutingContext`.
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Server.js

```
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Path = require('path');

const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 3000});

//React Junk
import React from 'react';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import reducer from './../common/Reducers/index.js';
import { match, RoutingContext } from 'react-router';
import Routes from './../common/routes/Routes.js';

const handleRender = function(req, res) {
    const store = createStore(reducer);
    match({Routes, location: req.url}, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
        //res(req.url);
        if(error) {
            res(error.message);
        }
        else {
            const html = renderToString(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <RoutingContext {...renderProps} />
            </Provider>
            );

            const initialState = store.getState();

            res(renderFullPage(html, initialState));
        }

    });
    // const html = renderToString(
    //  <Provider store={store}>
    //      <App />
    //  </Provider>
    // );

    // const initialState = store.getState();

    // res(renderFullPage(html, initialState));
}

const renderFullPage = function(html, initialState) {
    return `
        <!doctype html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Please Work</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="app-mount">${html}</div>
                <script>
                    window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(initialState)}
                </script>
                <script src="/static/bundle.js"></script>
            </body>
        </html>
    `;
}

server.register(require('inert'), (err) => {
    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/static/{filename}',
        handler: function (req, reply) {
            reply.file('static/' + req.params.filename);
        }
    })
    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        handler: function(req, res) {
            res('hello world');
        }
    });
    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/{path*}',
        handler: function(req, res) {
            handleRender(req, res);
        }
    })

    server.start(() => {
        console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
    })
})
```

Routes.js

```
import { Route } from 'react-router';

//Components
import App from './../components/App.jsx';
import Name from './../components/Name.jsx';

export default (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="test" component={Name} />
    </Route>
);
```

Because they were asked for

Client entry.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import App from './../common/components/App.jsx';
import Router from './../common/routes/Router.jsx';
import reducers from './../common/Reducers';

const initialState = window.__INITIAL_STATE__;
const store = createStore(reducers(initialState));

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router />
    </Provider>
, document.getElementById('app-mount'));
```

Client Router

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';
import createHashHistory from 'history/lib/createHashHistory';

const history = createHashHistory();

import Routes from './Routes.js';

export default (
    <Router history={history}>
        <Routes />
    </Router>
);
```

Comment: What does your client-side render code look like?  Are those errors client-side errors?  Or server-side errors?

Comment: I've added Client Entry and Client Router to the post. I believe they're server side?

Although I have this error in my console



Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `history` as a prop to `Router` on the client:

```
export default (
    <Router history={history}>
        <Routes />
    </Router>
);
```

The likely problem with your server-code is that you aren't passing the routes to `match` correctly.  It expects a property named `routes`, not `Routes`.  Try this:

```
match({routes: Routes, location: req.url}, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
```

Especially note this statement from the [documentation](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#match-routes-location-options--cb):

```
If all three parameters are undefined, this means that there was no route found matching the given location.
```

Comment: When I do that, I still receive the same errors:

Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `history` was not specified in `RoutingContext`.
Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `location` was not specified in `RoutingContext`.
Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `routes` was not specified in `RoutingContext`.
Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `params` was not specified in `RoutingContext`.
Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `components` was not specified in `RoutingContext`.

Comment: in the browser console or on your server?

Comment: They are server side errors. It seems like routing on the server is not passing anything in for renderprops?

Comment: You were exactly right about the named parameter issue. The react router server side rendering doc didn't mention that at all. That'll teach me not to dig into the actual functions :/ Thank you much for your help!